# SQL multiple conditons on a single column

Tags: sql, oracle, join, case

I need to display the records of a table using a WHERE clause which in turn depends on another column's value.

Say for example, list out the tables which consumes >200000 bytes and Indexes which consumes >100000 bytes from the table dba_Segments

Below is what I tried

```
select o1.segment_name,o1.bytes from dba_segments o1
inner join 
( select segment_name,bytes from dba_segments where segment_type='INDEX' and bytes>10000000) o2
on o1.segment_name=o2.segment_name where o1.segment_type='TABLE' and
o1.bytes>20000000;
```

The output is `no rows selected` I believe the WHERE clause is cancelling out each other.

I would like to get both the records (tables and indexes).

Please suggest the most efficient way to achieve this.

Although I'm a dba, I'm not so good at SQL.

Comment: Are there any more segment types (than index and table)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a join, just combine both conditions with an `OR`

```
select segment_type, segment_name, bytes 
from dba_segments 
where (segment_type = 'INDEX' and bytes > 10000000)
   or (segment_type = 'TABLE' and bytes > 20000000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want without using a join, but rather with an or condition:

```
SELECT
    segment_name,
    bytes
FROM
    dba_segments
WHERE
    (segment_type='INDEX' and bytes>10000000)
    OR
    (segment_type='TABLE' and bytes>20000000)
```